# How should I debug an app running on server in Django 1.3/Postgres 8.4 when local is Django 1.7/Postgres 9.3?

Tags: python, django, macos, postgresql

As a Django / Python newbie, should I try to debug on a server running 4 year old software versions, try to recreate the old software installations on my local, or just try to run the software in current version of Django/Python/Postgres/PostGIS on my local Mac OS X 10.9.5?

Background:

On a project where I was supposed to just load data into Postgres/PostGIS, I need to debug why a 2010 year old Django / Postgres / Postgis project is getting an error. I'm a LAMP developer who's never used Django or done much in Python, but I've been able to get a staging site working on the server, and make one or two changes. I thought it would make sense to debug locally on my Mac OS X 10.9.5. So I've used homebrew to install Django 1.7 and Postgres 9.3. Looking at the version differences, I'm worried it will be a more of a hassle now to try to migrate and upgrade the project than to attempt to debug it on the staging site instance running on the server.

FWIW, I know the lines of code that I'd like to investigate (seems like maybe an object is not getting loaded properly from db, since it is in the db), but I'm not positive what sort of echo statements to use. I like using IDE's to inspect things. The project is a bit of an orphan, as the first professional project of a developer who is no longer available to help. And of course, the deadline is last week. :(

Comment: Why didn't you install the correct versions of Django and Postgres locally?

Answer (score 3):

Differences between your production and development environments can cause a myriad of headaches.

I recommend you use a tool such as [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) to set up a development environment running inside of a virtual machine that mirrors your production server.

Comment: Worth mentioning that with vagrant/virtualbox you'll be able to use an IDE on your Mac to edit code, whilst also being able to manage the environment in the LAMP stack you're familiar with.

Comment: Thanks, bismark your suggestion sounds good. The project uses virtualenv, but I think that that would only  be relevant inside the python/ django version. I'll test that out.

Comment: John Mee, is there a good django IDE that supports remote debugging on the staging instance of the production server?

Answer (score 2):

Use [VirtualEnv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to emulate the necessary Django version. PostgreSQL is trickier, in theory you can have a second instance with the required version running simultaneously, but that can also cause very subtle conflicts. It would be better to have it running on another machine (virtual or physical) and access it through your local network.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way I think is to look at using [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) and [mock object](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) to set up some unit tests on the functions that you suspect are the cause of the problem. By using unittest and mock objects, you can control how the existing code interacts with Django and Postgres objects and allow for version differences by setting the expected return values.

With mock object, you can mock all or just part of an existing Python object, which reduces the dependencies you require for your development environment. Depending on how the code is structured, you might not need to install either Django or Postgres at all or a webserver for that matter. [This blog](http://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) explains Mock object in detail.

Even though you're pressed for time, you could do worse than setting up unittests for the whole project, future developers will thank you.

In terms of debugging, I personally can't reccomend [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) enough, it's an interactive command line debugger which you can use with unittest to zero in on what part of the code is causing the problem.

If you do need to install Django and Postgres, I would suggest looking at [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which allows you to set up a virtual environment for Python. That way you can just install the specific dependencies you need without interfering with your global system wide installation. You can also install earlier versions of packages which would do the trick to emulate the existing system's state.

Comment: He's worried about what versions of Django/Postgres to use, not *how* to debug a program.

Comment: What I have suggested makes the choice of version irrelevant or the use of virtualenv as an alternative to emulate the existing environment. My read of the OP is that he is looking for a way to debug in a language he is unfamiliar with.

I'm curious to see your suggestion though.

Comment: It looks like he is way behind schedule and already has an idea of the problem area. Install the right version of Django/Postgres and drop some `print` statements. Figure it out and ship it to production. *Then* worry about unit tests/vagrant/etc.